# Residue of $\frac{e^{-ikz}}{\cosh z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I am asked to compute the residue of
$$\frac{e^{-ikz}}{\cosh z}$$
Consider the zeros of $\cosh z$:
$$z=\frac{\pi(2n+1)i}{2}$$
Now consider:
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow\frac{\pi(2n+1)i}{2}}{\Bigr(z-\frac{\pi(2n+1)i}{2}\Bigr)\Bigr(\frac{e^{-ikz}}{\cosh z}\Bigr)}$$
Using l'Hopital's Rule:
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow\frac{\pi(2n+1)i}{2}}{\Biggl(\frac{-ike^{-ikz}\Bigr(z-\frac{\pi(2n+1)i}{2}\Bigr)+e^{-ikz}}{\sinh z}\Biggl)}$$
Which simplifies to:
$${(-1)^n e^{(2n+1)k\pi/2}}$$
which is apparently incorrect, the limit is suppose to return an imaginary value, not a real one. Where is the error? I suspect misuse of L'Hopital's Rule or maybe this is a higher order pole, but I don't see why.

Comment: Let $\alpha_n$ be a zero of $\cosh$. Note that all zeros of $\cosh$ are simple i.e. $\cosh'(\alpha_n)\not=0$. Now, $$\lim_{z\to \alpha_n}(z-\alpha_n)\frac{e^{-ikz}}{\cosh z}=\lim_{z\to \alpha_n}\frac{e^{-ikz}}{\frac{\cosh z-\cosh \alpha_n}{z-\alpha_n}}=\frac{e^{-ik \alpha_n}}{\sinh \alpha_n}$$

Comment: I don't see any mistake in what  you have done.

Comment: $\sinh \frac {(2n+1)\pi}{2} i = i(-1)^n$ which would give you the imaginary value you are looking for.